# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'user')

Tags: reactjs, axios

I want to get (mohammad) in my console but when I use: console.log(user.user.name), I give TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'user')  !
why?
What can I do?
thank you guys

```
export const Shopping = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    if (!token) {
      setUser(null);
      return;
    }

  
    const response = {
      data: {
        user: {
          name: "mohammad",
          email: "mohamad@gmail.com",
        },
      },
    };
    if (!response.data.user) {
      setUser(null);
      return;
    } else {
      setUser({ user: response.data.user }); console.log(user.user.name);
    }
  }, []);


  return (
    <div className="Shopping-Container">
      <NavbarStore user={user} />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Store />} />
     </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </div>
```

Comment: Its initialed as a null, why you expect to have an other value?

Comment: thanks Dennis but I continue have response variable and I  setUser({ user: response.data.user })   so my user isn't null   I think

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Initially, in the first render, `user` state has a value `null` and thus `user` cant have a property.

WHat you can do to prevent is:  `console.log(user?.user?.name);`

`user?.user` means that js will only try to get the `property only if the user is not undefined or null`, if `user is null`, then it will not move forward and `null will be printed`.

Same in the case of `user.user?.name`, if `user.user` is not null, the it will get the `name property` otherwise print `null`

Answer (score -2):

The error clearly say what's going wrong. It is because your initial value of `user` is `null`. That's why when you do `user.user.name` that error appeared.

Think you had set the value by `setUser({ user: response.data.user });`? Nope, it's not executed right away. The component will render first, then, your code in the `useEffect` will be executed.